# Automate Controls for Curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, automation

I am looking to automate (simplify) the path drawn in blue on my MWE. I am trying to avoid nodes if possible as this is nested in a `tikzpicture`.

Ideally I was hoping to simply specify the begin and end coordinates and adjust the step so to speak and perhaps amplitude. Perhaps using `pgfplots`

This is the result of my MWE: (crappy screenshot)

[image: Sample]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{snakes,backgrounds,arrows,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{rbox/.style= {draw=black,fill=white,thick,rectangle,rounded corners,inner xsep=2pt, inner ysep=2pt},
    fancytitle/.style={fill=blue!15,draw=black,thick,text=black,rectangle,rounded corners},}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
\node [rbox] (box) {
\begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}
     { 
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,sharp corners,x=1cm,y=1cm,
                every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
\clip       (0,-0.5)            rectangle           (6,6);
\draw    [help lines]    (0,0)          grid        (6,6);
%   Axes
\draw   [<->,>=triangle 45]         (0,3)           --          (6,3);
\draw   [<->,>=triangle 45]         (3,0)           --          (3,6);
\draw   [decoration={ticks,amplitude=.75mm,segment length=5mm},decorate,line width=0.75pt]
                            (0.5,3)     --          (5.5,3);
\draw   [decoration={ticks,amplitude=.75mm,segment length=5mm},decorate,line width=0.75pt]
                            (3,0.5)     --          (3,5.5);
%   Line
\draw   [*-*]                   (0.5,0.5)       --          (5.5,5.5);
%   Counting
\draw       [->,line width=1pt,blue]                (0.5,0.5) .. controls (.65,0) and (.85,0) .. (1,0.5)
                                            .. controls (1.15,0) and (1.35,0) .. (1.5,0.5)
                                            .. controls (1.65,0) and (1.85,0) .. (2,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
     }
\end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle,right=8pt] at (box.north west) {Grid:};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than giving control points, you can specify a curve using `to` and the options `bend right=<angle>` and `looseness=<...>`. I added the following to your code:

```
\draw [->,line width=1pt,red] (0.5,0.5) 
to[bend right=80,looseness=2.5] (1,0.5) 
to[bend right=80,looseness=2.5] (1.5,0.5) 
to[bend right=80,looseness=2.5] (2,0.5);
```

If you would like even more automation, you can get TikZ to calculate the sequence `1`,`1.5`,`2` of x-values from a given `\startx` value and `\step` between values, like so:

```
\def\startx{0.5}
\def\starty{0.5}
\def\step{0.5}
\def\finishx{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\nextx{\startx+\step}
\pgfmathsetmacro\nextnextx{\startx+2*\step}
\draw [->,line width=1pt,red] (\startx,\starty) 
\foreach \x in {\nextx,\nextnextx,...,\finishx} {
  to[bend right=80,looseness=2.5] (\x,0.5)
};
```

In any case, the result is:

[image]

---

**Update.** I noticed that your black blobs aren't quite centred in their respective grid squares. That's because  TikZ draws arrow tips so that the *end* of the arrow tip is the specified point. In your case, I presume that you want the *centre* of your arrow tip to be at the specified point. You could fix this by drawing the blobs as nodes, and then connecting them with a line, like so:

```
%\draw   [*-*] (0.5,0.5) -- (5.5,5.5);
\node[shape=circle,fill=black,outer sep=0mm] (a) at (0.5,0.5) {};
\node[shape=circle,fill=black,outer sep=0mm] (b) at (5.5,5.5) {};
\draw (a) -- (b);
```

---

**Update 2.** To get...

- an additional sequence of arcs extending *vertically* from the same starting point, and
- a numeric label on each arc

... you can use the following code.

```
\def\startx{0.5}
\def\starty{0.5}
\def\stepx{0.5}
\def\stepy{0.25}
\def\finishx{2}
\def\finishy{2.25}
\pgfmathsetmacro\nextx{\startx+\stepx}
\pgfmathsetmacro\nextnextx{\startx+2*\stepx}
\pgfmathsetmacro\nexty{\starty+\stepy}
\pgfmathsetmacro\nextnexty{\starty+2*\stepy}
\draw [->,line width=1pt,red] (\startx,\starty) 
\foreach [count=\i] \x in {\nextx,\nextnextx,...,\finishx} {
  to[bend right=80,looseness=2.5] node[green, auto, swap] {\tiny\i}  (\x,\starty)
};
\draw [->,line width=1pt,red] (\startx,\starty) 
\foreach [count=\i] \y in {\nexty,\nextnexty,...,\finishy} {
  to[bend left=80,looseness=2.5] node[green, auto] {\tiny\i} (\startx,\y)
};
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to also include a `count` of each step as a `label`?

Comment: Yes. Below each "valley", or above each "peak"?

Comment: Below each valley. But also, how can I adjust the code to do the same for the y-axis. I tried manipulating the code but to no avail.

Comment: By "the same for the y-axis", do you mean you want another sequence of arcs extending upwards from the same point?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I mean. I was a bit vague.

Comment: Done `:-)`. See updated answer.